# Parsing with a FOR command in a .BAT file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm having a bit of trouble with a FOR DO command in a .BAT file I'm working on for work.
Here is the entire code I'm working with

```
SET parent="%~dp0"
SET GroomedDir="%~dp0Groomed\"
XCOPY /s/e/y Groomed %parent%NewGroomed\
CD NewGroomed

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    FOR %%i in (IMG_*.jpg) DO (
    SET OldName=%%i
    SET ImgNumber=!OldName:~4,-4!
    SET DBLookup=FINDSTR !ImgNumber! Database.txt
```

---

```
    !DBLookup! > return.txt

    FOR /F "tokens=1-5 delims=|" %%J in (return.txt) do (
```

---

```
        REN !OldName! "%%K_%%L.jpg"
        MKDIR %%M\%%N
        MOVE "%%K_%%L.jpg" %%M\%%N
    )

)
del return.txt
endlocal
cd ..
ren Groomed "Groomed Backup"
ren NewGroomed Groomed
```

The trouble come in lines 12-14 (I put in line separators). I can't seem to put the variable %DBLookup% into the FOR command, and am forced to use a placeholder text file instead. It works, in the end, but wouldn't it be better to save myself the write to return.txt operation, and the read return.txt operation?

For context, return.txt contains a single line from of text like this:

115525|Last_First|5233|8|Teacher

I use the FOR command because it allows me to delimit using the pipe character, or whatever else, and output to %%J %%K %%L %%M and %%N variables.

Any help or advice for this relative newcomer is much appreciated!

Here's my code with my comments:

```
  REM THESE FOUR LINES: 
  REM 1) SET A VARIABLE FOR THE PARENT DIRECTORY LOCATION, 
  REM 2) SET A VARIABLE FOR THE GROOMED DIRECTORY, 
  REM 3) COPY THE GROOMED DIRECTORY TO "NEWGROOMED\", 
  REM 4) CHANGE THE LOCATION TO BE WORKING ENTIRELY WITHING NEWGROOMED\
SET parent="%~dp0"
SET GroomedDir="%~dp0Groomed\"
XCOPY /s/e/y Groomed %parent%NewGroomed\
CD NewGroomed

  REM THIS FOR LOOP LOADS ALL JPGS IN THE \NEWGROOMED\ DIRECTORY THAT BEGIN WITH THE STRING, "IMG_"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    FOR %%i in (IMG_*.jpg) DO (
    SET OldName=%%i
  REM THIS LINE COPIES THE OLD NAME MINUS THE FIRST FOUR CHARACTERS, "IMG_", AND MINUS THE EXTENSION (LAST 4 CHARS)
    SET ImgNumber=!OldName:~4,-4!
  REM THESE NEXT TWO LINES LOOK UP OUR IMAGE NUMBER IN DATABASE.TXT AND RETURN THE ENTIRE LINE TO A NEW FILE CALLED RETURN.TXT
    SET DBLookup=FINDSTR !ImgNumber! Database.txt
    !DBLookup! > return.txt
  REM NOW WE PARSE RETURN.TXT USING PIPE DELIMITERS INTO THE VARIABLES J,K,L,M,N (ID,Name,IMG#,Grade,Homeroom)
    FOR /F "tokens=1-5 delims=|" %%J in (return.txt) do (
        REN !OldName! "%%K_%%L.jpg"
        MKDIR %%M\%%N
        MOVE "%%K_%%L.jpg" %%M\%%N
    ) 
)
del return.txt
endlocal
cd ..
ren Groomed "Groomed Backup"
ren NewGroomed Groomed
```

Overall, my goal is to begin with a folder, "Groomed," with a bunch of images titled as such: IMG_####.jpg.

My batch file will:

1) create a backup of the entire starting directory

2) rename each image according to the database.txt file

3) move each renamed image into a new grade/teachername folder

I am starting with a file, (database.txt) that comes to me from another employee. The file is a plain list for each student in the following format: student id|lastname_firstname|image#|grade#|teachername.

As i mentioned. The file works perfectly, but since I'm new to batch files I was feeling like it might be dumb of me to write to a throwaway file just to save a string and then delete it. That's what variables are for, but I was having a hard time getting that variable to pass into the FOR command.

sample of Database.txt

```
659968|Saperstein_Ryan|4603|7|Hallock
015520|Qian_Emily|2528|7|Hallock
528852|Rizzo_Jason|4618|7|Krukowski
```

and a few filenames I'm starting with:

```
IMG_2528.jpg
IMG_4544.jpg
IMG_7044.jpg
IMG_6880.jpg
IMG_4839.jpg
```

Comment: Hey Paul, I'll paste my commented version in a large block at the end of my question. THANKS!

Comment: edit: it formats poorly here so i'll add it to the end of the question again!

Comment: Exactly Correct on the renaming. I want sure how to combine filename only and delete Img_ at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

A first bunch by parsing `database.txt` first and then compare by using `if exist`. The second is by comparing variables

***code:***

```vb
rem create a sample of the following example
rem :: student id|lastname_firstname|image#|grade#|teachername
rem :: The common points are only in the first 3 jpg

copy nul IMG_4603.jpg
copy nul IMG_2528.jpg
copy nul IMG_4618.jpg
copy nul IMG_4619.jpg
copy nul IMG_4620.jpg
copy nul IMG_4630.jpg


(
echo 659968^|Saperstein_Ryan^|4603^|7^|Hallock
echo 015520^|Qian_Emily^|2528^|7^|Hallock
echo 528852^|Rizzo_Jason^|4618^|7^|Krukowski
echo 528817^|Rizzo_Jas17^|4617^|7^|Krukows17
echo 528816^|Rizzo_Jas16^|4616^|7^|Krukows16
)>sample.txt

rem :: type sample.txt
rem :: pause
```

**Method #1**

```vb
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=|" %%a in (sample.txt) do (
  set "student_id=%%a"
  set "student_name=%%b"
  set "student_image=%%c"
  set "student_grade=%%d"
  set "student_teacher=%%e"
  rem :: echo !student_name!_!student_image!.jpg

  if exist "IMG_!student_image!.jpg" (
    rem :: remove echo in the following lines if it's okay.
    echo:
    echo ren "IMG_!student_image!.jpg" "!student_name!_!student_image!.jpg"
    echo mkdir "!student_grade!\!student_teacher!"
    echo move "!student_name!_!student_image!.jpg" "!student_grade!\!student_teacher!"
  )
)
```

**Method #2**

```vb
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (IMG_*.jpg) do (
  set "OldName=%%~i"
  set "image_number=!OldName:~4,-4!"
  rem :: echo image_number: !image_number!

  for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=|" %%b in (
  'findstr !image_number! sample.txt'
  ) do (
    set "student_id=%%a"
    set "student_name=%%b"
    set "student_image=%%c"
    set "student_grade=%%d"
    set "student_teacher=%%e"

    if "!student_image!"=="!student_image!" (
      rem :: remove echo in the following lines if it's okay.
      echo:
      rem :: echo !image_number! = !student_image!
      echo ren "IMG_!student_image!.jpg" "!student_name!_!student_image!.jpg"
      echo mkdir "!student_grade!\!student_teacher!"
      echo move "!student_name!_!student_image!.jpg" "!student_grade!\!student_teacher!"
    )  
  )
)
```

**output:**

> ```vb
> ren "IMG_2528.jpg" "Qian_Emily_2528.jpg"
> mkdir "7\Hallock"
> move "Qian_Emily_2528.jpg" "7\Hallock"
>
> ren "IMG_4603.jpg" "Saperstein_Ryan_4603.jpg"
> mkdir "7\Hallock"
> move "Saperstein_Ryan_4603.jpg" "7\Hallock"
>
> ren "IMG_4618.jpg" "Rizzo_Jason_4618.jpg"
> mkdir "7\Krukowski"
> move "Rizzo_Jason_4618.jpg" "7\Krukowski"
> ```